# URL is not interacting with server

Tags: jquery, html, ios, cordova

Using this URL:

```
http://mesto.nu/mesto/index.php?service=Service_Person&operation=getPerson&params={%22user_id%22:%687456%22,%20%22user_token%22:%232323227acb58da8c44c05c3bb12124113a0e2f55302fed84ed941b7f78a95111%22,%20%22person_id%22:%098678%22}"
```

in the browser produces this JSON:

```
"HEJSA{"errorCode":0,"data":{"name":"Niklaas Maverick Ingstrup","sex":"Mand","sex_id":"1","marital_status":"Single","marital_status_id":"2","birth_date_stamp":"672357600","image_url":"http:\/\/83.221.133.106\/pictures\/default\/person\/big1.gif","orig_image_url":"http:\/\/83.221.133.106\/pictures\/default\/person\/orig1.gif","per_favourite_place":"Minibar","checkin_venue_name":"null","friend_status":0,"blocked":false,"lat":null,"long":null,"visible":false,"fields":[{"field_id":"12","field_name":"Beskrivelse","values":[{"value_id":"2829","value_text":"20 \u00e5rig \u00f8konomi studerende ved \nKU. "}]}]}}"
```

How can I trigger this URL in HTML or JavaScript or jQuery? I want to use in PhoneGap for iOS.

Comment: Please format your code for readability

Comment: I suspect English is not your native language, and that is fine, but please take care of some basics. Like formatting, but also spelling of stuff you obviously should know (like the word `json`)

Comment: I tried to edit and fix your question up a bit. Please review and check if it still represents your origional question.

Comment: Check your code in emulator? It working there?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are authorized by this web application with some sort of API key, or by the administration of this site, it will be very difficult to catch the JSON in a useful way. Your domain will not be allowed by Access Control.

More on cross-domain AJAX:

http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/

Otherwise, in jquery, it's as easy as:

`var jsonObject = $.getJSON("http://yourlongurl.com");`